# Can I enter a value into cell A1 on Sheet 2 and have it automatically add to a value in cell A1 in Sheet 1?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, office365

I have a workbook that contains several worksheets which is used to calculate fees based on hours. Sheet 1 contains the base work hours, while each additional sheet is used to add hours to the values in Sheet 1. Say that I estimate 8 hours in cell A1 of Sheet 1, but I want to add an additional 8 hours in cell A1 Sheet 2 (or Sheet 5, for that matter). I want to be able to just type 8 in A1/Sheet 2 and have 16 be the result without having to enter formulas in each cell.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not. You should have Sheet0 which sum all cells that you have/want. Or if you do not touch Sheet1 values - it may stay there.

Answer (score 0):

USE [3-D reference](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Create-a-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-c906f8b4-c648-4aa0-8063-65d38d03370f), it's the best way to work with a range of cells in multiple sheets.

To do that, I will use your example to show you how it's done:

Say that I estimate 8 hours in cell A1 of Sheet 1, but I want to add an additional 8 hours in cell A1 Sheet 2 (or Sheet 5, for that matter). I want to be able to just type 8 in A1/Sheet 2 and have 16 be the result without having to enter formulas in each cell.

So, we have 3 Sheets, Let's say that Sheet 1 is the Summary sheet. in Sheet 2, we put **A1** `=8`, and Sheet 2 **A1** `=8`. In the Summary sheet, **A1**`=SUM(Sheet2:Sheet3!$A$1)`

This will result that cell A1 in Summary sheet will be **16**.